# How to improve the code of a method which uses 'Free monad'?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, refactoring, monads, scalaz

I'm trying some code which inspects [this slides about `Free Monad` in Scala](http://www.slideshare.net/kenbot/running-free-with-the-monads?qid=b8e19675-797b-4c88-a2a4-953afb21ef98&v=default&b=&from_search=1), and made a small project with some slightly changed code.

The project is here: https://github.com/freewind/free-the-monads

Everything seems good at first, the [code is clean and beautiful](https://github.com/freewind/free-the-monads/blob/master/src/main/scala/app/KVStoreDemo.scala#L7-L23):

```
def insertAndGet() = for {
    _ <- Script.insert("name", "Freewind")
    value <- Script.get("name")
  } yield value

  def insertAndDelete() = for {
    _ <- Script.insert("name", "Freewind")
    _ <- Script.delete("name")
    value <- Script.get("name")
  } yield value

  def insertAndUpdateAndDelete() = for {
    _ <- Script.insert("name", "Freewind1")
    oriValue <- Script.update("name", "Freewind2")
    _ <- Script.delete("name")
    finalValue <- Script.get("name")
  } yield (oriValue, finalValue)
```

But when my logic is complex, e.g. there is some `Script[Option[_]]`, and I need to check the option value to decide to do something, I can't use the `for-comprehension` any more, [the code is like](https://github.com/freewind/free-the-monads/blob/master/src/main/scala/app/BigKVStoreDemo.scala#L25-L35):

```
private def isLongName(name: String): Script[Boolean] = for {
  size <- Script.getLongNameConfig
} yield size.exists(name.length > _)

def upcaseLongName(key: String): Script[Option[String]] = {
  Script.get(key) flatMap {
    case Some(n) => for {
      isLong <- isLongName(n)
    } yield isLong match {
        case true => Some(n.toUpperCase)
        case false => Some(n)
      }
    case _ => Script.pure(None)
  }
}
```

I found the `Free Monad` approach is really interesting and cool, but I'm not familiar with `scalaz`, and just beginning to learn `Monad` things, not sure how to improve it.

Is there any way to make it better?

---

PS: You can just clone the project https://github.com/freewind/free-the-monads and try it yourself

Comment: You may want take a look at this https://github.com/pelotom/effectful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a good use case for the `OptionT` monad transformer:

```
import scalaz.OptionT, scalaz.syntax.monad._

def upcaseLongName(key: String): OptionT[Script, String] = for {
  n <- OptionT.optionT(Script.get(key))
  isLong <- isLongName(n).liftM[OptionT]
} yield if (isLong) n.toUpperCase else n
```

Here `OptionT.optionT` converts a `Script[Option[String]]` into an `OptionT[Script, String]`, and `.liftM[OptionT]` raises a `Script[Boolean]` into the same monad.

Now instead of this:

```
println(upcaseLongName("name1").runWith(interpreter))
```

You'd write this:

```
println(upcaseLongName("name1").run.runWith(interpreter))
```

You could also have `upcaseLongName` return an `Script[Option[String]]` directly by calling `run` there, but if there's any chance you'll need to be composing it with other option-y script-y things it's probably best to have it return `OptionT[Script, String]`.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. A small future question: If I also use some other types like `Seq`, do I need to involve some other transformers like `SeqT`?

Comment: @Freewind Right—if you want to end up with a `Script[Option[List[A]]]`, for example, you'd use a `ListT[OptionT[Script, ?], A]`. Lifting from the different layers gets unwieldy pretty quickly, though.